# Google Chrome shows error in console, although error handling is defined within the function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling, console, httpresponse

I have the following function, which requests data from Google Analytics API and gets a response as a JSON Array:

```
// Query the Core Reporting API from Google Analytics with the defined variables

function requestResponse() {

  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + $('input[name="hiddenProfileId"]').val(),
    'start-date': $('input[name="hiddenStartDate"]').val(),
    'end-date': $('input[name="hiddenEndDate"]').val(),
    'metrics': metricsArrayOutput.join(","),
    'dimensions': dimensionsArrayOutput.join(",")

// If response isn't an error, then change div background to pale green and show a "Tree View" of the JSON obtained
  }).then(function(response) {
    $("#responseOutput").empty();
    $("#responseOutput").JSONView(response.result, {collapsed: true});
    $("#responseOutput").css("background-color", "#bef7be");

// Handle error: change div background to pale red and show the error Objects of the JSON obtained
  }, function(errorResponse) {
    $("#responseOutput").empty();
    $("#responseOutput").JSONView(errorResponse.result.error, {collapsed: false});
    $("#responseOutput").css("background-color", "#FBDDDD");
    alert("bad things happen to everyone");
  })
}
```

It's the first time that I use the then() method, and although at the beginning I had some problems trying to handle the error responses (because initially I defined only the argument for success case), it works really good now and I love how easy I can handle all the not 200 HTTP Responses.

However, in Google Chrome (v. 47.0.2526.106) Console I am getting a weird "GET error" when the response isn't a 200 HTTP Response:

> GET
>   https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?{parameters_that_result_in_error_response}
>   400 (OK)

{parameters_that_result_in_error_response} is the combination of variables sent to the API that generates an error response.

As I said, the function works and its general goal is achieved, but I don't understand why this error is being shown. When the http response is a 200 one, nothing is sent to console, so I can imagine that the .then() is sending this error to the console itself, although it's handled in the code some lines after. Do you know how to resolve this incongruence?

**Note:** No error is shown in IE or Firefox.

Comment: That's how google chrome dev tools work, it show http errors in console.

Comment: @jcubic thx for the comment. For me, until now, a clean, errorless console was a synonim of a good code. I believe that I have to change my assumptions :)